# After applying subtheme to wso2, store tags are not appearing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After I applied subtheme to wso2 store tags are not appearing.

[image]

Comment: Have you check what's there in <AM_MOME/repository/deployement/server/jaggeryapps/admin/site/blocks/api-availability/ajax/api-availability.jag file line number 71?

Comment: Line number 71:parsedDataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);

Comment: i have added my subtheme in site.json like below and then i have created a folder in 
wso2am-2.1.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\site\themes\wso2\subthemes

    "theme" : {
        "base" : "wso2",
  "subtheme" : "<sub-theme-name>"
    },

Comment: Just analysed my logs and these logs were not related to tags but the other issues so i have edited my question and removed the logs

Comment: further more i have analysed and found that if i don't give name without    -group then tags appears for example if i give my tag as api or api-grp then it shows in my tags.

Is it a bug in wso2.1 because in wso2.0.0 we were able to see our tags if give name <apigroupName>-group

Comment: I found that there is change from wso2 2.0.0 to wso2 2.1.0 related to Tags.
Below file is having logic for displaying Tags.
So in this file if tag name is present with <tag-Name>-tags then this name will be ignored and only tag name will be considered if it doen't have tag name without '-tag'
wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/tag/tag-cloud/template.jag

I hope this will help others.

Comment: Can you please add this as answer and accept it?

Comment: I am not able to add this as answer , not sure what needs to be done .
may be question was asked by me so i am not able to add answer for this question.